# HAProxy - stop catering requests on 500 from server

Tags: ubuntu, haproxy

Is there any way to stop catering further requests to server from HAProxy when a bankend server sends a 500?

When a server receives a signal like SIGINT, it will start serving "500 Server Internal Error" . SO when HAProxy detects 500 response from server, will it be able to stop further requests to the server?

There is a macro "on-error" which is enabled by default in server section. Trying that did not yield any result. For example:

```
server nucleus_server1 127.0.0.1:12341 check on-error mark-down
```

.the macro on-mark-down is not working along with this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the `httpchk` option?  It will fail for responses that are not 2xx or 3xx, and HAProxy will stop sending traffic to that machine.

From the [official documentation](https://code.google.com/p/haproxy-docs/wiki/httpchk):

```
# Relay HTTPS traffic to Apache instance and check service availability
# using HTTP request "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1" on port 80.
backend https_relay
    mode tcp
    option httpchk OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:\ www
    server apache1 192.168.1.1:443 check port 80
```

But it can be as simple as:

```
    option httpchk GET /_health
```

where `/_health` returns a good status code.

Comment: Note that this works different from the original configuration. With checks, HAProxy performs active requests and only checks the results of those. It will not inspect "regular" traffic. For that, you have to use `observe layer7 error-limit 10 on-error mark-down` or similar as answered by @user3365898. You would also need to enable checks.

Answer (score 8):

If you want HAProxy marks server as DOWN based on return code sends by this server add 'observe layer7' option to server definition. For your example, it could look like:

```
server nucleus_server1 127.0.0.1:12341 check on-error mark-down observe layer7 error-limit 1
```

It means that if nucleus_server1 returns 500 to any client request it will be removed from the pool. By 'error-limit' you can configure how many 500's have to be returned to mark this server as 'DOWN'.

Server will be marked as 'UP' again if internal HAProxy check success (by default 2 times).

Take a look on: check, fall, raise, error-limit, observe options in HAProxy documentation for more info.